# Secure connections between App Service and Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I want to enable a secure connection (https only) between my App Service and Application Insights. As I have read [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/application-insights-telemetry-data-now-requires-https-with-shutdown-of-http-data-collectors/), the newer SDKs use https only.

How can I check the application insights endpoint, or the SDK used in my web app ? I am using the Application insights tab in my web app to configure the application insights.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answered your own question as per the below:

> From December 5, 2016, Azure Application Insights will no longer accept telemetry data sent using HTTP. Only HTTPS data will be accepted. This change is being made to improve security.
>
> This change will affect your app only if it uses a very old version of the Application Insights SDK. All telemetry sent by recent versions uses HTTPS by default. About 1% incoming telemetry for Application Insights uses HTTP.
>
> Here's what you can do:
>
> Update the Application Insights SDK used by your servers and apps to the latest version. All versions from the last six months send HTTPS by default.
>
> Check that your webpages use a recent version of the JavaScript SDK snippet. The correct snippet should include a reference to: https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js
>
> A new version of the snippet is available from the Getting Started tab in your
>
> Application Insights resource in the Azure portal. (You can also get it from GitHub, but substitute your app’s instrumentation key.)
>
> **If you see a drop-in telemetry volume after December 5**, update your server applications to use the latest version of the Application Insights SDK. (How to upgrade: ASP.NET, Java.)
>
> We always welcome feedback.

The above assumes that if you weren't using HTTPS, you wouldn't be seeing any telemetry.

[See endpoints here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the SDK that your Web App is using in the Kudu Console / ApplicationInsights, i.e.:

> https://YourWebApp.scm.azurewebsites.net/ApplicationInsights